# Need to rewrite code for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the code I need to rewrite to work on SQL Server 2008. The code below works in SQL Server 2012 and above since it uses the `LAG` windowed function.

Can anyone help me on this?

```
LAG(AccountKey) OVER(ORDER BY AccountKey) AS PREC
```

---

I guess I need to add some details

[Click on this line to see a screenshot of table with data that the code I sent solves. But I need to rewrite the LAG Function to work with SQL 2008](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5jAc.png)

```
SELECT AccountKey,
       LineName,
       AccountName,
       GroupKey,
       AccountNumber,
       ParentAccountKey
INTO tempAccount
FROM
(
    SELECT AccountKey,
           LineName,
           AccountName,
           GroupKey,
           AccountNumber,
           AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey, 
           LAG(AccountKey) OVER(ORDER BY AccountKey) AS PREC
    FROM tempTable2
    WHERE GroupKey IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.AccountKey,
           A.LineName,
           A.AccountName,
           A.GroupKey,
           A.AccountNumber,
           B.AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey,
           B.PREC
    FROM tempTable2 A
         INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT AccountKey,
               LineName,
               AccountName,
               GroupKey,
               AccountNumber,
               AccountKey AS ParentAccountKey,
               LAG(AccountKey) OVER(ORDER BY AccountKey) AS PREC
        FROM tempTable2
        WHERE GroupKey IS NULL
    ) B ON A.AccountKey < B.AccountKey
           AND (B.PREC IS NULL
                OR B.PREC < A.AccountKey)
    WHERE A.GroupKey IS NOT NULL
          AND B.GroupKey IS NULL
) X
ORDER BY AccountKey;
```

Comment: Show us the code :-)

Comment: A title should give at least an idea of what the problem is about. Once the question is answered, it should help people having the same problem to find the sollution.

Comment: I've editted your post with your "answer" (although awaiting approval), however, images aren't helpful for SQL queries. you need to provide DDL and **consumable** Sample data, as well as your expected result set. SQL Server can't query or interact with images.

Answer (score 1):

We've not got the full picture here, as we only have details on a single column, however, this should get you where you need to be.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT YourColumns,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AccountKey) AS RN
    FROM YoutTable)
SELECT YourColumns
       C2.AccountKey
FROM CTE C1
     LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RN = C2.RN + 1;
```

Comment: I don't know why my code was deleted. I will try to add it again

Comment: @GeirForsmo Looks like there was a pending edit that was approved after you made the edit.

Comment: Succeeded to add the code. Sorry about the mistakes. I am not using stackoverflow that much